# mysql case within select statement

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

1) visit table

```
visit_id     |   visit_date    |   premises_name
   1             2012-04-25        abc
   2             2012-04-25        xyz
   3             2012-04-25        yio
```

2) sample table

```
visit_id    |   sample_id     |   item_name
   1               abc_332          lmn
   1               xyz_342          pqr
   2               lsl_324          plk
```

Each visit can have multiple sample

i want the query which output the following result

```
visit_id   |  visit_date |  is_sample_taken
   1          2012-04-25         YES
   2          2012-04-25         YES
   3          2012-04-25         NO
```

i searched a lot but could not fine the solution. please help

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: i could'nt understand what u mean?

Comment: @user1543848, you are suggested to follow Jon Skeet's blog post on [writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Its very important that you supply an example of what you have done and failed.

Comment: @Vic. thanks for advice. now i understand why Marcin Orlowski commented in very rude way. next time i will definitely follow your advice. anyhow, with help / hint given by Hiren Dhaduk, i solved my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like :

```
select visit_id , visit_date , case when sum(case when b.visit_id is NULL then 0 else 1 end) > 0 then  'YES' else 'NO' end as sampletaken
from visittable as a LEFT OUTER JOIN sampltetable as b on a.visit_id = b.visit_id   
group by visit_id , visit_date
```

Answer (score 0):

with the help / hint from Hiren Dhaduk answer i got the solution of my question

```
SELECT v.v_id, v.v_date, (
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT sample_id
        FROM sample
        WHERE visit_id = v.v_id
    )
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
) AS is_sample_taken
FROM visit v
```